# Returning a redirect from a child function

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am working on a Symfony project.  It has custom access controls set up (that are dynamically created and stored in a database.)  As such, I've created a custom BaseController class that allows me to do a one-liner call to verify access.  Here's some of that code:

```php
class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    function prepare($customer, $product, $right) {
        // These are all defined in the class.  
        $this->loadCompany($customer);
        $this->canAccessProduct($product);
        $this->checkAccessRights($customer, $product, $right);
    }
}
```

The prepare method is called at the top of every controller.  For example:

```php
class IndexController extends BaseController {
   /**
     * @Route("/{customer}/download",
     *     name="download_home")
     */
    function customerIndex($customer)
    {
        $this->prepare($customer, "download", "read");
    }
}
```

Now here's the change I want to make: I want to remove the {customer} from the route and instead load it as part of the "prepare" function call.  As such, I want to store the customer in the session variable.  If the session variable is not set, I want to redirect to a different controller.  This is accomplished in Symfony using `return $this->redirectToRoute("app_company_select")`.  So can I set it up so a return call in `$this->prepare()` that returns the controller function as well?

I have attempted `parent::return()` but that gives an unknown function error.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with calling redirectToRoute directly from the prepare method?

Comment: @slepic sadly, that won't work. The redirectToRoute needs to be returned from the main controller method. Otherwise Symfony won't do the redirect.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that your flow (if no session variable set) would be customerIndex --> prepare --> getSession/Customer --> do prepare stuff --> continue in customerIndex? Or would the prepare() function redirect to another branch of logic altogether?

Comment: You need to return redirect response from child, by chaining `return`. Alternatively, you can return some boolean flag with `true` value meaning "do a redirect". Alternatively you can set some global value to `true` (global in a sense of services, e.g. you can set some flag in a service which is injected into your controller, or if everything happens in your controller you can use some new controller field), and later in controller check that flag and return redirect. There is nothing magical in controllers, they are more or less normal PHP functions, so, all usual means work.

Comment: @ehymel The workflow is will be customerIndex-->preapre-->checkSession.  If hasSessionVariable-->do prepare stuff and let the controller execute.  Else redirect to a customer picker.

Comment: @alx I understand that.  I was hoping to avoid touching every method to check for any sort of global flag.  That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Also you can make your own kind of exception and then catch it in your controller. But this is very dirty. Well, maybe not *very* dirty if you are redirecting to a page like 404 or 403, or login page -- basically this is what Symfony already does with thing like `throw $this->createNotFoundExpception();` and `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted()`.

Comment: Actually, your code looks pretty much like custom voters. Why not use built-in voting system instead, along with `denyAccessUnlessGranted`? https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just redirect right from where ever you are. As long as you havent sent any headers yet this should work fine.

```
public function prepare(...)
{
    $hasAccess = false
    // Check for access
    if(!$hasAccess){
        (new RedirectResponse('/go/somewhere'))->send();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in my comments, I'm hoping to avoid touching every controller to check any sort of flag.

Comment: Then in the check it self just send the redirect response and exit

Comment: @MatthewB I updated my answer to reflect the possible solution. If you want to have symfony generate the route for you too, then you could inject the router into what ever class you are using for your checks.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you!  It works like a charm.